# Html Agility Pack: a simple "Sanitizer" with dictionary parameters

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.5, html-agility-pack, htmleditorextender, sanitizer

Seach engine wasn't enough for information about shape of dictionary parameters of

```
    AjaxControlToolkit.Sanitizer.HtmlAgilityPackSanitizerProvider sanitizer = 
    new AjaxControlToolkit.Sanitizer.HtmlAgilityPackSanitizerProvider();

    textBoxPublicInput.Text =
    sanitizer.GetSafeHtmlFragment(
            textBoxPublicInput.Text,aDictionary,anotherDictionary
                                 );
```

What must I put in the aDictionary and anotherDictionary parameters? What must the elements be? I see it needs a string to array of string dictionary but which strings? What are the rules?

Lets assume trusted tags are < a >, < p >, < div > and < ul >- < li > only.
Main intention is to protect site against injections because of the html editor extender.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

*The following applies to the `AjaxControlToolkit.HtmlEditor.Sanitizer` [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AjaxControlToolkit.HtmlEditor.Sanitizer/)*

You need a `Dictionary<string, string[]>` where the key is the elementname (eg. `p` and the value is an array of allowed attributes for that element (eg. `style`, `class`).

```
    var validHtmlTags = new Dictionary<string, string[]>
    {
        {"p", new[] {"style", "class", "align"}},
        {"div", new[] {"style", "class", "align"}}
        //etc ...
    };

   var sanitizer = new AjaxControlToolkit.HtmlEditor.Sanitizer.DefaultHtmlSanitizer();
   var sanitized = sanitizer.GetSafeHtmlFragment(toBeSanitizedText, validHtmlTags);
```